# Modeling two parallel aggregate, entity, value object hierarchies

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity, value-objects

I'm struggling with the following domain design that seams not to fit within the concepts of DDD as I understand them.

In one hand, I have the Device->Sensor->Measurement hierarchy, modeled as an Aggregate with Device as as the root, Sensor as an Entity and Measurement as a VO. So far so good.

Now, each device has a type, as does the Sensor. At the same time Measurements refers to a variable been measured (e.g. temperature).  Here is where things break apart.

I initially modeled types as Value Objects, but there's a limited set of types and many devices and sensors share the same types.

I then decided to model them as an aggregate, following a similar structure than the device aggregate: DeviceType->SensorType->Variable. However, this doesn't work as Sensors may reference to SensorType and Measurement to Variable, breaking the rule of only allowing references to the root of an aggregate from inside another aggregate. Besides, It may happen than more than one DeviceType includes the same type of sensor (e.g. a battery charge sensor) and also that more than one Sensor measures the same variable (e.g. battery charge level).

This leads me to having each of those entities (DeviceType, SensorType, Variable) as independent entities, each in its own (degenerated) .

My concrete question is: have I correctly interpreted the notions of Aggregate, Entity, VO or having such anemic aggregates with solely the root an anti-pattern?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you posted some of the code that you have so far.

Comment: There's no code so far. I'm still modeling the domain. I tried to submit an image but the system didn't allowed me to do so as I'm a new user.

Comment: pablochacin, did you ever come up with a suitable way of modelling your domain? I have a similar situation...

Comment: @oakman I ended up creating the two parallel aggregate hierarchies and made references between elements of the same hierarchy, what brakes the rule of not referencing but the root of an aggregate. I think, however that casablanca's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules in modeling, you should do whatever fits your use case best. That being said, aggregates are mainly used for maintaining invariants across a group of entities. I don't see any such constraints between DeviceType, SensorType and Variable, hence I don't see any reason to put them into an aggregate. It should be fine to keep them as independent entities (or even value objects).

Comment: The point of not modeling DeviceType, SensorType and Varibale like Value Objects is that they are not simple attributes of Device Sensor and Measurement (respectively), like the typical address example. They are defined once as part of the configuration of the system and then referenced by the other entities. That's what puzzles me. 

I suppose, as you point out, that maybe they should be treated as independent entities.

Comment: @pablochacin: In that case, yes, you can model them as entities but keep them independent. There is nothing wrong in having entities that are not part of aggregates.